# How exactly does imageAtomicExchange work?

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, shader

I have a texture of vec4's which is being modified by the compute shader.

Different invocations of the compute shader modify different components of the same vector and this seems to be causing some concurrency problems as currently my method for doing so is:

```
vec4 texelData = imageLoad(Texture, texCoords);

//Do operations on individual components of texelData based on the invocation id

imageStore(Texture, texCoords, texelData);
```

I imagine what happens here is that different invocations are getting the original state of texelData which would be all 0's, writing their bit to it, then storing it which means only the component modified by the last invocation to finish will be present at the end.

So I'm looking into using imageAtomicExchange which should do this atomically, therefore eliminating the concurrency problems, however I cannot get it to work.

The [spec](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/imageAtomicExchange.xhtml) says that the arguments are:

- The image2D to write to
- The vec2 coordinates in the image to write to
- A float.. which I don't understand?

Would it not be a vec4 as that is what is present at each texel? And if not shouldn't there be another argument or an extra dimension of the coordinate vector to specify which component of the texel to swap?

Comment: Before OpenGL 4.5, atomic operations only worked on textures formatted with either `GL_R32I` or `GL_R32UI`, which only has one component.

Comment: In that case do you know any way of modifying a single component of the vector without the concurrency problems?

Comment: Also what about OpenGL ES does it support GL_RGBA32F textures?